# What is Debian's equivalent of do-release-upgrade to upgrade the operating system? (for example, from stretch to buster)

Tags: debian, apt, upgrade, aptitude, dist-upgrade

Ubuntu's [do-release-upgrade](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man8/do-release-upgrade.8.html) command upgrades the operating system to the latest release. What is Debian's way or tool for the same purpose (to upgrade to the latest stable release)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Debian does *not* provide a single command to upgrade the OS to a new release.  The Release Notes for each release include upgrade instructions for supported hardware architectures.

You can find release notes for all Debian releases via the [Debian Releases](https://www.debian.org/releases/) page.

For example, to upgrade a 64-bit PC from *stretch* to *buster*, follow the instructions in [Chapter 4. Upgrades from Debian 9 (stretch)](https://www.debian.org/releases/buster/amd64/release-notes/ch-upgrading.en.html) under [Debian 10 -- Release Notes for Debian 10 (buster), 64-bit PC](https://www.debian.org/releases/buster/amd64/release-notes/).

You should always be able to find the release notes for the current stable release at https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/releasenotes.

Although upgrading a Debian release from "[oldstable](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianOldStable)" to stable is usually painless, it's important to follow the Release Notes because the OS can differ from release to release in ways that could affect your specific installation.

The Release Notes also contain information and tips about changes in the new release that can save considerable time and effort.
For example, the upgrade process for some previous releases recommended the use of `aptitude` for the upgrade.
For upgrades from *stretch* to *buster*, the `apt` tool is recommended instead of `aptitude`.
(Although `aptitude` is suggested for resolution of some problems *after* the upgrade.)

Comment: why can't Debian grab the do-release-upgrade from Ubuntu and make a part of a Debian? It's looks for me like a very important tool. Did Canonical tried to make the tool as part of upstream Debian?

Comment: @SergeyPonomarev It is a misconception that do-release-upgrade is a convenience tool - it is a workaround, because dist-upgrades regularly break on Ubuntu, and it is expected. Instead of fixing their repositories and release processes, they came up with a wrapper script that makes a best effort to pull everything straight around the breakage. In Debian, the workarounds are not needed.

Comment: So the Debian has something like rolling releases? The do-release-upgrade makes some additional things to make it safer to upgrade: expose a separate SSH on 1022 port. Maybe something else, don't remember.

Comment: @SergeyPonomarev, Yes, "Testing" is the name of Debian's rolling release.  The current Testing release is codenamed Trixie, and is scheduled for release to stable around 2025.  I like Debian Testing on my workstation (instead of Ubuntu) and only Debian Stable on servers.

Answer (score 2):

Officially, there's no tool - you're supposed to take care about it on your own: see https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/release-notes/ch-upgrading.html, for example.

Basically, it revolves around changing/adding URLs to repository for newer version and upgrading packages, sorting out any trouble that might come. You can see in the guide that it's not really convenient. This is why many distributions don't provide way to upgrade between releases, or strongly discourage it - there's a lot to care about (and also why it's often good to use LTS or rolling release distributions).

There might be an unofficial tool to automate the process in Debian, but I would rather follow the documentation in that respect.

Comment: In my experience, upgrading Debian is pretty easy. I think I've made every Debian stable→stable upgrade since slink on at least one machine.